# Fire checkbox event with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.2.0.

I am trying to implement the [vertically grouped checkboxes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/).

I need to detect changes on the checkboxes. An example is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Maxbester/z4UQC/).

However, it doesn't work on my page (which I don't give because it contains too many dependencies but the code is the same).

Basically, when I click a checkbox, the following message should be displayed in the console:

```
INPUT
module1
-----
```

Whereas in my page I've got:

```
FIELDSET
moduleListTitle
-----
DIV
moduleContainer
-----
DIV
(an empty string)
-----
```

I've spent hours trying to find why the event is not fired correctly.

Has anyone already faced this problem?

Comment: You may need to `.trigger('refresh')` after inserting the checkboxes dynamically. on JSfiddle you provided is working normally. so try `$('#moduleListTitle').parent().trigger('refresh');` after `('create')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing the code live - not on JSfiddle - I have reached the below solution.

Since the items are added dynamically, you should bind the event to `$(document)` and the handler to `'input:checkbox.module'`.

Here is the code, I hope it solves your problem.

```
$(document).on('change','input:checkbox.module', function(){
 console.log(this.tagName);
 console.log(this.id);
 console.log("-----");
});
```

`trigger.('refresh')` is not required here.

Comment: I am glad I have been of help :) I really don't know, but I assume that JSF treats them as static elements not dynamic ones. I should dig more into this subject and find out the reason.

Comment: @user3765109 you're welcome. A better method to attach listener to dynamic elements is to delegate `change` event from _parent_ static element (not added dynamically) e.g. `$("#static_parent").on("change", ".dynamic_element", function () { /* code */ });`. http://jsfiddle.net/z4UQC/23/ If you have doubts, post a new question :)